# I get a NullPointerException when i try to modify the height of a layout in onTabSelected()

Tags: android, tabs, nullpointerexception

Here is my quite simple problem:

I get a NullPointerException when i try to modify the height of a layout in onTabSelected().

Here is the code:

```
import...

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ...
        tab1.setTabListener(new MyTabListener(fragmentTabCustom));
        actionBar.addTab(tab1);
    }
    ...
    public void changeFragmentTabCustom() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {    
                layout1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutdefault);
                layout1.getLayoutParams().height = 0; // the exception appends on this line
                layout1.setLayoutParams(layout1.getLayoutParams());
            }
        }
    }
    ...
}

public class MyTabListener implements ActionBar.TabListener {
    ...
    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        mainActivity.changeFragmentTabCustom();
        ...
    }
}
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Can you please add some more code snippet.

Comment: Check to make sure `getLayoutParams` isn't returning a null. If it is, you may to initialize something prior to calling the `get`. In that case, check the documentation.

Comment: Where is that method (onTabSelected) declared and used ? the error is most likely due to layout1 not being part of your Activity's layout.

Comment: Where layout1 is placed? in fragment that in tab or in activity that contains tabwidget?

Comment: Please see the edited code.

Comment: Do i need to complete my question or to ask a new question to get a solution?

Answer (score 0):

This happens because your view's layoutparams are set by the Parent(Viewgroup).

Wait till the view is attached to the window (add onlayout listeners) or you can create new LayoutParams with hight as "0".

Comment: I think the problem could come from the fact that layout1 is not yet created when onTabSelected() is called. Could you explain your solution?

Comment: I tried a ViewTreeObserver. It gets a NullPointerException too because the layout on wich i try to put this observer has not yet been created... Any idea on how i can modify a layout in a fragment in a tab each time it is selected??? HELP

Comment: Do i need to complete my question or to ask a new question to get a solution?